# Get changed text from rich textbox

Tags: c#

So, I am looking for the best way to get the text that has changed either using the keyPressed event, put preferably the TextChanged event. What I'm looking for is what has been changed. I have a program that should send events to another window and populate the rich textbox there with a color. I tried the following using the keyPressed event:

```
 private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     char keyChar = (char) e.KeyChar;
     if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(keyChar) || Char.IsSeparator(keyChar) 
        || Char.IsWhiteSpace(keyChar))
     {
         string changedText = keyChar.ToString();
         VinduEventArgs ve = new VinduEventArgs(colorDialog1.Color, changedText);
         VinduEndret(this, ve);
     }
 }
```

But it doesn't really work as it's buggy, doesn't show all signs, and seems kindof like a bad solution.

Comment: why don't you use colordialog? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.aspx

Comment: Why don't you compare editor text content (previous vs actual) ? you could then send an event based on the diff.

Comment: I do use colordialog, but I need to send the changed text in the eventargs. I have tried that as well, but it is equally buggy.